# What could be the cause of this if condition getting skipped even the condition inside is True?

Tags: c++, xcode4, osx-mavericks, compiler-optimization, adobe-indesign

I am debugging a C++ project (A Plugin for Adobe InDesign) for a bug on OSX 10.9.5 using XCode 4.6.2. I have encountered very strange problem in the following code, the if statement in the following code is getting skipped even when the condition inside it is valid/true. When control reaches this if statement the value of insertSinglePageElement is 1, insertSinglePageElement is a bool16 variable. 
It must return true, still the code inside the if block is getting skipped.

Also, Does Xcode allows you to see the corresponding Assembly code? If yes then how?

```
bool16 insertSinglePageElement = kTrue;
...
//code
...
if(insertSinglePageElement == kTrue)
        {
            msgs = insertPageElementToPage(pe, pageData->grid, &pageName, pageData->presentationID, IDPageElementMap, true);

        } else {
            //Else Block
```

[image]

[image]

Above images show the value of variable and debugger showing the skipping of code in the second image by one step from the first one.

Comment: How is `kTrue` defined? What happens if you write `if(insertSinglePageElement)`, without the `== kTrue`?

Comment: Are you debugging with optimizations off?
If you have optimizations on, the code you run might not be the exact same as the code you wrote

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger and verified that everything has the values that you think it should have?

Comment: @fredoverflow kTrue is defined in the InDesign SDK I am using for the plugin, Yes I used    if(insertSinglePageElement)  but the same thing happens.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer Yes I did step through the debugger and and when it comes on the if condition the value of bool16 variable insertSinglePageElement is 1.

Comment: @Abhishek Then what makes you believe that the code is being skipped?  Try adding a breakpoint on that line inside of the if and see if it trips.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer When debugger is stepping through the code it comes on the if condition, Shows the value of variable in output and skips the whole code inside the if block and enters the else block despite the value of variable (when its checking the if condition) is True. Yes I checked it by adding breakpoints inside 'if' block.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Thanks for the advise. After turning optimizations off the value of variable got changed which makes why the condition was failing but still changing value of a variable based on whether optimization is on or off is weird.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this problem was that the TRUE block which XCode4.6.2 (Using Apple LLVM 4.2) showing to be true was not true. After turning Optimization on, X-Code started showing it as False.